# Show error message in an alert box; without removing the data in textfield in yii

Tags: php, yii

actionCreate:

```
        try
        {
        $this->saveModel($model);
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->showError($e);
                    }
```

function showError:

```
  function showError(Exception $e)

   {
    if($e->getCode()==23000)
        $message = "This operation is not permitted because it exists in a record.";
    else
        $message = "Invalid operation.";
    throw new CHttpException($e->getCode(), $message);



  }
```

If error is found this redirects to a window where the error is shown. How to show the error in an alert message rather than redirecting, and without removing the user entered value from textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

try storing the value entered by the user in variable upon submission.
it can look something like this:

```
<form class="signup_form" name="signup_form" method="post">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for='username'>Username:</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input type='text' id= 'username' name='username' placeholder='Username' maxlength='15' value="<?php echo $input->value('username');?>"/>
        </dd><span id='error-msg'><?php echo $input->error_msg('username');?></span>
    </dl>
</form>
```

notice that the "value" attribute gets its value from $input->value('username') which i have set to receive the value entered by the user upon form submission:

```
$this->input[$pointer]['value'] = $_POST['username'];
```

note:
$input is an instance of the Input class i have created to handle input validations. You can do it another way. the idea is to store the value in a variable upon form validation and load it again when page is loaded.